# What could be causing one circuit out, no breakers thrown, and other lights to flicker?

Tags: electrical

We've recently had what looks like 1 circuit in the kitchen go out, affecting 2 outlets. I checked the circuit breaker panel and none are thrown. A couple other nearby lights have flickered several times in nearby rooms. Same with the garage door when I opened it. The weather has recently gotten warmer and more humid so the AC is running more, but I don't see a correlation between AC running and lights flickering. We just got back a couple days ago from being gone a week. While we were gone a couple rounds of strong thunderstorms went through. Must have knocked out the power because some of the clocks were reset, including the microwave, which is near the outlets that are out. But the stove's clock was not reset.

Any idea what's causing this?

I did a search here for flickering lights and have read a couple other questions and answers. Unfortunately I don't have any equipment to test things.

Answer (score 3):

OK, at first I thought bad back-stab connection at a receptacle, but since this is affecting several places in the house with obviously several varied circuits I would all but guaranty you have a bad line in to your service. This could be anywhere from the connections at the utility pole, to the connections at the top of your house, to inside the meter pan, to the connections to the main breaker in your panel.

Typically this is NOT something for a DIY to troubleshoot. PLEASE call in a qualified electrician to check it out. You may want to contact your utility first, they may send someone out for free to check their side of things.

Comment: The symptoms match what I saw recently in my house, and it was a bad line. We called the power company at 9pm, by 4am they had it fixed. I would recommend that you call the power company.